# What are my options for a disk with what seems to be a corrupted filesystem?

Tags: mount, data-recovery, disk-utility, filesystem-corruption

I have a friend with an old Dell that will not boot into Windows.

It has an IDE drive.  It spins up.  I have an IDE to USB device.  I've attached the drive via that device to a working laptop.  The drive does not mount.  If I go into Disk Management I can see the drive but it will not initalize, says "Drive not ready."

I've also booted into a linux live cd to see if the drive mounts, it does not.

I am just trying to recover some pictures from the drive.  The data is not important enough to send to a professional.  The issue is more of a curosity on how to recover data if and when these situations would occur in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try using "testdisk" to see what the drive's partition table looks like, and recover / rewrite if possible.

Comment: The drive is not listed.  Does it have to be mounted before to show?

Comment: no - should have worked without. - ditch this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

[SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) might be able to help if it is bad sectors or if that isn't the issue you can use [GetDataBack](http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm).

GetDataBack has a demo in which you can see what it would recover before you purchaes so it is worth checking out. SpinRite on the other hand doesn't have a demo but I would highly recommend it, it is amazing what this software does.

Comment: I tried GetDataBack.  It does not see the drive.  I have only been able to see the drive using Disk Management.

Comment: Give SpinRite a try then, sounds like more then just a file system error.

Comment: HDD Regenerator is similar to Spinrite and costs less...http://www.dposoft.net/